# @Remote JNDI Communication: Wildfly to JBoss AS 5.1.0.GA

Tags: java, maven, jboss, jndi, wildfly-8

Architecture:
Windows Client -> Wildfly JAX-RS Services -> JBoss 5.1.0.GA legacy system.

I am getting a java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.naming.Reference cannot be cast to com.interfaces.GroupBookingManagerRemote when communicating here  between Wildfly JAX-RS Services and JBoss 5.1.0.GA legacy system.

As I am communicating from Wildfly to JBoss AS 5.1.0.GA I am attempting to connect using JNDI.

In my Wildfly Server Maven pom I include:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jboss</groupId>
    <artifactId>jnp-client</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.2.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

This gives me access to the required org.jnp.* classes and interfaces.

I simply use the following code to connect to my remote machine and retrieve back a GroupBookingManager. However the issue appears when I attempt to cast the class to the interface GroupBookingManagerRemote.

```
Properties env = new Properties();
env.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://myremoteserver:1099");
env.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
env.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces"); 
InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext(env);

Object ref = initialContext.lookup("MyEARFile/GroupBookingManager/remote");
if (ref != null) {
    bookingManager = (GroupBookingManagerRemote) ref; // java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.naming.Reference cannot be cast
}
```

I have a myclient.jar file which I have added to my Wildfly application that contains the remote interface GroupBookingManagerRemote.

Does anyone see any issue with what I have done?

Thanks,

Darren

Comment: Man this is going back with a time machine... possibly you don't cast the Object but you need to do PortableRemoteObject.narrow(ref, GroupBookingManagerRemote.class); (don't know if it is correct, I dug it up from REALLY old company wiki articles)

Comment: Unfortunately this then gives me the following:    java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.naming.Reference cannot be cast to org.omg.CORBA.Object

Comment: Then it is probably the dependency that is wrong. that version is odd - it looks like you're using a dependency from JBoss 4.2.2 for JBoss 5.1. JBoss always has a generic jboss-as-client dependency that is for connecting to a JBoss server from a client, try using that. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.jbossas/jboss-as-client/5.1.0.GA

Comment: Hi Gimby, I see what your getting at however in maven I can only find version 4.2.2 as the latest jnp-client. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jboss/jnp-client

Comment: But you're ignoring the other half of my comment.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your help Gimby,

I found the answer myself after a bit more messing about.

From Wildfly 8.1.0 (client) -> JBoss AS 5

You do not require any JBoss 5 jars

Firstly you need a reference to the interface that you wish to use on the client side. This can be in a your-project-client.jar. If using Maven you can create a repository and build the Maven directory structure using mvn

```
mvn install:install-file -DlocalRepositoryPath=DirectoryName -DcreateChecksum=true -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=Path-to-you-project-client.jar -DgroupId=YourGroupId -DartifactId=YourartifactId -Dversion=1.0
```

Then in order to connect to the remote machine and cast the interface back to your-interface, you use:

```
final Properties env = new Properties();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.class.getName());
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://remoteserver:4447");
InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext(env);
```

This uses Wildfly remote:// which is in remote naming and ejb in wildfly-ejb-client-bom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.0.Final</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

And I also required this dependency for communication

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.xnio</groupId>
    <artifactId>xnio-nio</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2.Final</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

and this one for the remote naming.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-remote-naming</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Also note the port is not the ususal port for JBoss 5 JNDI:1099 this is the Default Remoting Port : 4447

```
Object ref = initialContext.lookup("ejb:Your-EAR/YourClass/remote!" + YouClass.class.getName());
```

You can then cast your reference to your interface and use it as normal.

Hope this makes sense.