# Remote EJB call from different JRE and Server version

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, compatibility, wildfly

In my work I encountered a situation where the right theoretical architectural solution is to call an EJB deployed on JBoss 4.3 (Java EE 5) running on JRE 1.6, from a Wildfly 8.1 (Java EE 7) instance, running on JRE 1.8.

Is this possible? What problems can I come across?

The question is about compatibility of

- Application Servers
- Runtimes
- Specifications and standards

I know there is workaround using Web-Services. If possible, please attach some link to compatibility table or some other resources.

Comment: We tried to invoke a Server on JBOSS EAP 7 (Java 1.8) from a Client on Weblogic (Java 1.6). Unfortunately it doesn't work with EAP 7 but apparently EAP 6.4 could do it (but since this is already out of mainstream support not a good option). As per Arjan's answer, the challenge is with Client classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the ability to call EJBs between application servers is very badly specified (read, not at all).

The problem is that in order to call a remote EJB you'd need a client library. This client library contains many classes that are normally part of an application server. This works perfectly when the client is a Java SE application, but causes major issues when the client is another Java EE application server (as many classes are clashing then).

The only exception is when the two application servers are the exact same make and version, since no client library at all is needed then.

So in general what you're trying to do already doesn't work, but since you're using JBoss it absolutely doesn't work. JBoss is notoriously bad in being able to call EJBs from other versions of JBoss. Much has been written about this, and many attempts have been made to workaround it, but as far as I know it never really worked.

Theoretically this could have been fixed in the EJB spec a long time ago, but EJB is more or less being decommissioned (its features re-implemented using other specs) so quite understandably there's very little impetus to fix anything here.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned the JRE versions while you didn't mention what was the JDK version used to compile both the service and the client codes.

As a rule, higher JRE version can run any compiled code using lower or similar JDK version. Same rule for code inter communication using client stubs. Higher versions can call lower versions while opposite is not possible. So, if the generated client stub was using JDK1.7 or 1.8 it won;t be possible to be called using JRE1.6 and you will get this error java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version ...

So, there is no problem as long you compile  code in at most JDK1.6

Answer (score 0):

[This Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26162850/132374) claims that it's possible for Wildfly to invoke EJB's in JBoss 5, so hopefully that would work for JBoss 4 also.  Best of luck!